# Cleanest way to parse some files by hand in SCons

Tags: scons

I want to pass some custom options to the linker based what is in a header file in my source tree. I'm doing something like this now and it works, but there's got to be a better way:

```
def getCustomStr():
  for l in open(Dir('#').abspath + "/header.h"):
    if "#define MAGIC_FLAG" in l:
      return munge_flag(l)


env.Append(LINKFLAGS['-Xlinker', getLinkOpt()])
```

In particular accessing `Dir('#')` like that gives me the creeps. Any better ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with using Dir('#')? That's standard SCons usage..  Can you be more specific about what you see wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

If `Dir('#')` gives you the creeps, try this instead:

```
for l in open(File('header.h').abspath):
```